# How to store vectored, year-indexed data in node properties in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a large database with many nodes `(:Node)`. These nodes are created in a given `(:Year)`, and that information is stored via `(n:Node)-[:CREATED_IN]->(y:Year)`.

For any year `y` I calculate, for all years `y..2020`, multiple scalar scores (similar to PageRank). I also calculate graph embeddings, which are vectors.

I want to store these scalars and these vectors for future calculation.

I've tried two approaches, neither of which is satisfactory:

(1) Create a different property for every score for every year for every node (for example, `2018_PageRank` and `2018_Word2Vec`). This is not ideal because I end up with hundreds and hundreds of properties, and it is more complicated to query.

(2) Create a vector for each scalar of size 2020, and then score the scalar score into the appropriate position of that vector. For example, PageRank score `s` for year 2018 would be in `n.PageRank[2018-1]`. But, this wastes space, and cannot be used for the vectorized embeddings.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the model I would store all the embeddings and PageRank scores as attributes of the new relationship :EMBEDDINGS

So your final model would be:

```
(:Node)-[:EMBEDDINGS{pagerank:1,embeddings...}]->(:Year{value:'2018'})
```

Edit due to comment

Comment: The problem with your solution is that every year >= the :CREATED_AT year is relevant. Thus, for `(n:Node)-[:CREATED_IN]->(y:Year)`, I will have embeddings and PageRank scores for every year from `y` to 2020.

Comment: In this case create a new relationship for each year... like the categorical pagerank concept... find more at https://neo4j.com/blog/categorical-pagerank-using-neo4j-apache-spark/

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Can you explain a bit more; where would the relationship be from/to? I assume the PageRank and embeddings for each year `y` would be stored as properties of this relationship? Also, how would you write a query to store the results, which are written to the nodes by default, to a relationship instead?

Comment: Check https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/neo4j-categorical-pagerank/

Comment: I did read the link you suggested, and as I said, it is interesting but not obvious how this maps onto my question. Could you elaborate/explain?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. I think that could work, but I'm worried about performance implications; each `(:Year)` node will have millions of incoming relationships (since each `(:Node)` will have edges for 100+ different years, and I have hundreds of millions of `(:Node)`s. Thoughts on optimizing this?